# Why this code got compile error in ANSI C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, ansi-c

I'm solving a basic C problem on a site called [UVa Online Judge](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1), and I encounter an error which seems to related to compiler options.

```
ANSI C 5.3.0 - GNU C Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -ansi -DONLINE_JUDGE
```

The problem(with problem id as prefix) is `UVa 100 3n+1 problem` as following. It can be compiled and run, without error, on Visual Studio 2019, the site reported "Compile Error" for it. The site will not show any error message, just `Compile Error` in its bulletin.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int get_cycle_length(int n);

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int l, r;
    int max;
    int n;
    int cycle_length;
    char line[10000] = { 0 };
    size_t line_len = sizeof(line), read_len = 0, pos = 0;
    while (scanf(" %d%d", &i, &j) != EOF) {
        l = i > j? j: i;
        r = i > j? i: j;
        max = -1;
        for (n = l; n <= r; n++) {
            cycle_length = get_cycle_length(n);
            if (cycle_length > max)
                max = cycle_length;
        }

        read_len = snprintf(line+pos, line_len-pos, "%d %d %d\n", i, j, max);
        if (pos+read_len > line_len) {
            printf("%.*s", (int)pos, line);
            pos = 0;
        }
        pos += read_len;

        // printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, max);
    }
    printf("%.*s", (int)pos, line);
    return 0;
}

int get_cycle_length(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 1) {
        count++;
        n = n & 1? 3*n+1: n/2;
    }
    count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: And what are errors?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I'm using VS2019 and I got no error, but after submission it only shows CE.

Comment: On first glance I would suspect this line: `    char line[10000] = { 0 };
`

Comment: @Devolus: I've tried move it to global and omit the `= { 0 }`, still got CE.

Comment: Try replacing the `//` comment with `/* ... */`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using C++ style comments in your code, i.e. `//`.

Many C compilers will allow these types of comments as an extension, however strict ANSI C does not.  You'll need to use C style comments `/* ... */`.

So instead of this:

```
// printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, max);
```

Do this:

```
/*
printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, max);
*/
```

Comment: Lol, I thought it was (and have tried them) `size_t`, or local `char line[]`, missing `#include<...>` (because IDE always help me too much..., i.e. auto-include behind the scene).